# Laravel accessor for camelCase property

Tags: laravel

I am trying to change the value of a property while returning data in json. It works for normal property name but camelCase doesn't work.

My property name `profilePic` I am trying like this

```
public function getProfilePicAttribute($profilePic)
{
    return "https://cdn.mydomain.com$profilePic";
}
```

Any suggestion?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am trying to change the value of a property while returning data in json."?

Comment: You have to do `$model->profilePic`... What is not working ? What is the error ?

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using? As far as I know, `profilePic` should resolve correctly to the mutator named `getProfilePicAttribute`. I've been using underscored property names everywhere in my database (like `profile_pic`) but both seem to work fine after analyzing the source code.

Comment: @Tpojka it means, when you return profilePic it need to return `profilePic : https://cdn.mydomain.com/uploads/pic.png` instead of `/uploads/pic.png`

Comment: @matiaslauriti, I returning json data which is later used in frontend, I am not using blade. Normally I see getAttribute work if I change a normal property, lets say email but camelCase property doesn't work

Comment: @Flame I am using Laravel`^5.8.0`.  Yes its strange if I give `getProfilePicAttribute` it doesn't work, but if I give getEmailAttribute and change the email it works.. so it has something to do with camelCase property. In my database, column name is `profilePic`

Comment: it could be that you have to name your column `profile_pic` then, even though I cannot find a difference in the code for this functionality since v5.8. Also you should really start upgrading since there are no more security patches for that version since it has long passed LTS

Comment: Upgrade in progress and will take time. In my database column name is `profilePic`

Comment: Thank you, but cannot change property name to profile_pic since many frontend consume this api as profilePic

Comment: My personal recommendation is to change to `profile_pic`, stick to Laravel naming standards... Also, I understand if this is a project already done and you had to work on it as it is, so it is not your fault, but you can change it and use [`API Resources`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources) (as you should be using) to return exactly what you want as formatted as you want, so there is no excuse about frontend like it like that...

Answer (score 1):

Ok thank you all, I solved it this way

```
protected $appends=['profilePic'];
public function getProfilePicAttribute()
{
   return "https://cdn.mydomain.com".$this->attributes['profilePic'];
}
```

Comment: nice. after search for a long time your solution worked like a charm